# Ping works, internet hotspot works on mobile but unable to access websites in laptop's browser

Tags: proxy, ping

I have a strange problem. I'm unable to access Internet on chrome in my laptop but I'm able to access sites in Mobile through my laptop's internet hotspot. I tried ping google.com and ping 8.8.8.8, both work fine. I'm using my college's LAN and I have tried changing proxy settings too. I 
 tried uninstalling antivirus programs too. Nothing seems to be working.

Comment: There is too much we dont know about your setup. This is likely proxy related, possibly authentication as well.