# Internet (mostly) works but unable to ping - how to diagnose?

Tags: linux, ipv6, ipv4, nixos

<sup>Found a couple similar questions ([1](https://superuser.com/questions/1497814/ping-works-internet-hotspot-works-on-mobile-but-unable-to-access-websites-in-la), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/1667547/unable-to-connect-to-router-or-ping-but-internet-says-connected)), but they don't exactly cover my issue and there are also no answers, so:</sup>

Dusted off an older laptop with linux (NixOS 21.11.337659.06db2e21974 (Porcupine)), started using it, no issues, suspended it when finished. Today, I dove into stuff as usual, but browsing was very slow, and at one point no sites started loading in Chrome; no connection issues, simply just hanging, not even showing that it is trying to load.

When trying to `ping`, this is what I got:

```
$ ping www.google.com
PING www.google.com(lga25s71-in-x04.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4006:80e::2004)) 56 data bytes
^C
--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4121ms
```

We have 2 wifi networks, let's call them `wifi24` (2.4 GHz) and `wifi5` (5 GHz). Tried switching back and forth, same issue. Feeling desperate, I turned on my phone's wifi hotspot while the phone was connected to `wifi24` - now I was able to browse and `ping` showed an IPv4 address when resolving the domain. When switching to `wifi5` on the phone, nothing worked again and `ping` resolved the domain to IPv6 address and showed only packet loss.

Rebooted the machine, reloaded the services with `systemctl` plus any combinations of these, same results. Gave up, suspended the laptop, and when I returned a couple hours later, browsing works, pages load (maybe slower than usual?), but `ping` still shows only packet loss (and IPv6 address, connected to `wifi5`).

---

In the end, I'm able to work, but bothers me that I don't understand what is happening.

- What tools would you recommend using to get to the bottom of this?
- I thought I understood the basics of networking, but apparently I missing some of the fundamentals so any good resources would also be welcome...

Comment: what happens if you force the ping to use ip4?

Comment: Since Nix OS 2.91 was released in May, 2022, why not try updating to see if that fixes the issue?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Because I also ran into issues when trying to upgrade, so I'm looking for solutions for that too..

Comment: @Albin Didn't even think about it.. Will try, thanks!

Comment: Are both "wifi24" and "wifi5" provided by the same access point, and are both connected to the same subnet? If it's the same IPv4 subnet, they both should offer the same IPv6 connectivity (or lack thereof) as well. Does your IPv6 default route actually go through wlan0 (and not through some unexpected VPN interface)? Does IPv6 work in other devices on the same LAN, and do they get assigned addresses with the same prefix? Where does `traceroute -I -6` lead you? (Could be simply an ISP issue, but also could be a rogue router pretending to provide v6 connectivity...)